# Como buenas practicas ¿Donde poner la generación de reportes PDF en una aplicación de N-Capas, en un Controller o Servicio API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Hola mi duda esta en que parte poner mi creación de reportes PDF en mi aplicación de N-Capas.

Utilizare itext-sharp para su creación, pensaba ponerlo en la aplicación de cliente (MVC) como una llamada al metodo de mi controlador, pero por hay vi ejemplos que esto de reportes lo ponen como un servicio web.

Yo como servicio web utilizo APIs con su respectivo CRUD.

¿Lo pondría como una llamada a mi controller o como un servicio web API la creación de reportes?

Si es con API, como sería el método para archivos.Y al hacerlo de esta forma ¿no sería muy pesado para el ancho de banda?
Por su atención gracias.

Comment: Hola Lalo, bienvenido a la familia de SOes, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y como tal, te doy mi punto de vista: Depende de la arquitectura de tu proyecto. Si es solamente para la web, con generarla en un controlador va bien. Por otro lado, quisiera que leas http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask de tal manera que la calidad de respuestas y preguntas aumenta en estos lares de la red. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por su opinión y los puntos para las preguntas, enterado.

Answer (score 1):

**>>¿Lo pondría como una llamada a mi controller o como un servicio web API la creación de reportes?**

La verdad no le veo mucho sentido exponer un webapi para generar un pdf, mas si esto lo vas a generar como parte de una view en un desarrollo asp.net mvc

Quizas si usaras Angular o si lo consume algun sistem externo si tendria sentido usar webapi.

**>>¿no sería muy pesado para el ancho de banda?**

El ancho de banda es lo mismo si envias el archivo a un webapi o si lo haces a un action del controller, el pdf generado pesara lo mismo en la transferencia al cliente sin importar la tecnica

**>>pensaba ponerlo en la aplicación de cliente (MVC) como una llamada al metodo de mi controlador**

Podrias hacerlo de esta forma sin problemas, simplemente generas el pdf

[Creating Dynamic PDFs in ASP.NET MVC using iTextSharp](http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/creating-dynamic-pdfs-in-aspnet-mvc-using-itextsharp-EV)

como veras en el articulo se genera el pdf en un action devolviendo un `FileContentResult`

Comment: Gracias, si ya tome una decisión y si lo haré en el controller, gracias por opinión y el aporte, son de ayuda.